# ios StoryBoard - Subclass of UIImageView is showing up as a UIImageView rather than the subclass in IBOutlet variable

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I have a subclass of UIImageView called SlideShowView.  The SlideShowView .h and .m files are in a shared project that is referenced from my main project.

In my storyboard, I have an instance of SlideShowView connected to an IBOutlet in my ViewController.

When I try to call the SlideShowView method `setImages:` on that instance, I get this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImages:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b57360`

When I do `po [self slideShowView]`, which is defined as: 
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SlideShowView *slideshowView;`, it shows up as `<UIImageView: 0x6b57360; ...`.

So it seems that for some reason, it isn't being set as an instance of my subclass, but an instance of UIImageView.

UPDATE:
If I copy the SlideShowView.m and .h files out of the shared library to my main project, it works.  So that makes me think it has something to do with storyboard not finding the shared library files.

UPDATE 2: I tried setting the customClass in the storyboard to `fkdsfewnwef`, and it didn't throw any error or anything, it just still shows up as a UIImageView. So now I'm pretty sure it has something to do with SlideShowView not being found in the linked static library project.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, select it and set it to be a SlideShowView in the Identity inspector. Otherwise, the storyboard cannot know what class it is intended to be.

Comment: Yes, I had already done that, and it is set to SlideShowView. But the problem is still there :(

Comment: Yeah, sorry; it's clearly all about the linkage from the static library. My answer is irrelevant. This article might help: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4